# What physically is the heap?

Tags: heap-memory, arm64

I am familiar with the *abstract* concept of the heap and how to implement in languages like C with `malloc`. But, I don't understand how the compiler allocates memory in what programmers call the "heap."

In ARM-64 machines (which is what I'm using), there is no physical stack and heap, just  RAM plus 15 registers in the CPU. How would a computer allocate a pointer on the heap, say for a dynamically-sized array? How does it decide which memory address to reserve? If I were to write a memory manager in A64 assembly, what roughly would that entail?

Comment: Are you asking from the point of view of an application running under an operating system, or the OS kernel itself, or code running on the bare metal without an OS?

Comment: @NateEldredge From the perspective of an application under an OS.

Comment: What makes you think the compiler has any involvement with the heap?